# Below is the html for an index page I've been working on. I want to edit and delete button in datatable but not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {  

        // New record
        $('#MyTable').on('click', 'a.editor_create', function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            editor.create({
                title: 'Create new record',
                buttons: 'Add'
            });
        });

        // Edit record
        $('#MyTable').on('click', 'a.editor_edit', function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            editor.edit($(this).closest('tr'), {
                title: 'Edit record',
                buttons: 'Update'
            });
        });

        // Delete a record
        $('#MyTable').on('click', 'a.editor_remove', function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            editor.remove($(this).closest('tr'), {
                title: 'Delete record',
                message: 'Are you sure you wish to remove this record?',
                buttons: 'Delete'
            });
        });

    $('#MyTable').DataTable( {  
        "processing": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments",
            "dataType": "jsonp",
            "dataSrc":""
            },

        "columns": [
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "email" },
            { "data": "body" }, 
            {
                data: null,
                className: "center",
                defaultContent: '<a href="" class="editor_edit"onclick="editor_edit()">Edit</a> / <a href="" class="editor_remove">Delete</a>'
            }


        ]
    } );  
} );  


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.editor_edit', function() {
    // do something
});
```